# What is the periodicity of $((a^n \text{ modulo } p) \text{ modulo } q)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, finite-fields

This feels like it should be elementary but it came up in my research and I was not able to solve it.

We can ask this question for any $p$ and $q$ but,let $p$ and $q$ be primes for simplicity. The sequence
$$ ((a^n \text{ mod } p) \text{ mod } q)$$
is periodic. What is its period?

Can you find a characterization in terms of $a,p,q$?
Clearly, it depends on the order of $a$ in $p$. If $p$ is less than $q$ the problem is trivial.

Comment: Clearly, the period divides the order of $a$
mod $p$. In most cases, they will be simply equal, but there may be some special choices of $a,p,q$ when the period is a proper divisor of the order.